# Translation of "user email" used in form fields in website

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

I have got the work to translate a website in French. I am a developer by profession so I do not know much about doing translations. I used Google Translate for this purpose but I am not sure as it gave me three different translations like this.

user = utilisateur
email = e-mail
Join them and it would become  "utilisateur e-mail"
and if I type all together in GT it becomes "messagerie de l'utilisateur"

Which one is right (if any)?

It's a very big project and we fetch emails from users with different domain. We are converting words to French that are static in the application. The translations I did with GT include:

User Email = Email utilisateur
User Name = Nom d'utilisateur
Customer User Name = Nom d'utilisateur client
Customer Name = Nom du client
Customer Username = Nom d'utilisateur client
Customer Email = Email client

I am really not sure which are the right ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is *user* in the expression *user mail* actually useful in your context ?  I mean, is there different email adresses the website wants to fetch (personnal/professionnal/other), or is it just your classic everyday form, with only main information ? In the latter case, just use *email*. In the former, an adjective should be used for disambiguation with other emails asked for. If, for an example, the form asks for *user email / sponsor email*, use *votre e-mail / e-mail de votre parrain*. Give us some context if you want a more precise advice.

**Edited after seeing the fields list :** Go for *e-mail utilisateur*, it should fit your context clearly enough. Though a little odd or possibly perceived as too litteral, I guess most french people have already come accross this near-anglicism translation as the most frequent on the web.

---

As a sidenote, some remarks made through reading your list :

---

> 'Contact Person Phone:' => 'Contactez Téléphone de la personne:'

...is a mistranslation. Try *Téléphone du contact*. Generally, translate *contact person* as just *contact* or maybe *interlocuteur*. We can then conclude than :

> *'Contact Person Name:'* should translate to *Nom du contact / de l'interlocuteur*

and

> 'Contact Person Email:' to *E-mail du contact / de l'interlocuteur*

(by the way, try to be consistent with your naming. *E-mail* or *courriel* are both acceptable, but randomly using one or the other is introducing a false distinction.)

---

> 'Welcome' => 'accueil' (why not *Bienvenue* ?)

---

> 'Please wait. Deleting user..' => "S'il vous plaît attendre. Suppression de l'utilisateur .."

No. Prefer *Veuillez patienter. Suppression de l'utilisateur en cours..*

---

> 'User saved successfully.' => "Benutzer-Registrierung ."

Here, I must admit I chuckled a bit. And my german friends too.

---

I didn't have more time for now but I quickly saw there are other errors in the rest of the list, though often minor ones. I'll edit tonight or tomorrow if nobody has done it yet.

Comment: I have updated the context on which I was working...thanks a lot of your help...but still these are the basic words every website has...if you can correct my translations it would be of great help....or you can also drop me a general advice.

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble qu'un certain nombre d'articles ajoutés rendent plus intelligible les étiquettes et messages, et aussi  en réserver l'utilisation des majuscules au premier mot :

```
"Enregistrement utilisateur" --> Enregistrement de l'utilisateur (si cela provient de 
    l'action  d'un utilisateur : "Enregistrement en cours"    

"Ajouter Type d'entreprise" -->  Ajouter le type d'entreprise

"ID Type d'entreprise" --> Identifiant du type d'entreprise

"Total Customer" --> Total du client (s'il s'agit d'une seule personne/Société) dans ce cas,
    les autres ".. à la clientèle" --> du client dans ce cas

"Total Modules" --> Total des modules, s'il s'agit d'une totalisation, sinon Modèle de Total,
     s'il s'agit d'un exemple

"App Access ID" --> ID (ou Identification) d'accès à l'application

'Loading templates for the selected business type..' --> Chargement du modèle selectionné
     pour ce type d'affaire

Saving Customer Configuration.. --> Sauvegarde de la configuration *du* client
```